# Personalizar el color de dentro y del borde de un triángulo en Canvas y poner las dimensiones de éste

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como veis el color es siempre el mismo necesitaría un botón personalizable de color de relleno del interior para que el usuario escogiera el color que desease eso para el interior y el contorno de la figura. Os dejo el código en uno solo para no tener que ir de un archivo a otro. Grácias!

```html
<!Doctype html>

  <html>

  <head>

  <title>Triángulo</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

  </head>

  <style type="text/css">

    body{

      background-color: #F1F1F1;

    }

    form {

      padding: 0;

      margin:10px 30px ;

      background-color: white;

    }

    *{

      margin: 0;

      padding: 0;

      font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";

    }

    input[type=button]{

      text-decoration:none;

      border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);

      font-size: 20px;

      color: #fff;

      cursor: pointer;

      display: inline-block;

      border-radius: 5px;

      height: 32px;

      width: 235px;

      background-color: #11B547;

    }

    /* boton al clickearlo sobre el */

    input[type=button]:active{

      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.00);

      color: #11B547;

    }

    /*este espara que el imput number se le quite las flechitas*/

    input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{-webkit-appearance: none;margin: 0;}/*google chrome y safari*/

    input[type=number]::-o-inner-spin-button{-o-appearance: none;margin: 0;}/*opera*/

    input[type=number]::-moz-inner-spin-button{-moz-appearance:none;margin: 0;}/* firefox*/

    input[type=number] {-moz-appearance:textfield; margin:5px;}/*firefox firefox 29*/

    input[type=number]::-ms-inner-spin-button{-ms-appearance: none;margin: 0;}/*internet explorer*/

    input[type=number] {

      cursor: text;

      text-indent: 5px;

      width: 355px;

      font-size: 20px;

      height: 30px;

      border-radius: 5px;

      margin: 0;

      background: linear-gradient(#342E21, #483F2E);

      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #483F2E inset;

      padding: 0px;

      border: none;

      color: #fff;

    }

    header{

      background-color: #fff;

      width: 100%;

      height: 50px;

 

    }

    header span{

      float: left;

      vertical-align:bottom;

      font-size:35px;

    }

    </style>

  <body>

    <center>

    

  <form name="f1">

    <h1>Triángulo personalizable</h1><br>

    <input type="number" name="txtn1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tamaño Horizontal">

    <input type="number" name="txtn2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tamaño Vertical">

    <br><br>

    <canvas id="miCanvas" width="720" height="450">Su navegador no soporta Canvas.</canvas>

    <br>

    <center>

    <input type="button" value="Dibujar" onclick="dibujar()">

    <input type="button" value="Limpiar" onclick="limpiar()">

    <input type="button" onclick=" location.href='index.html' " value="Volver al Inicio" name="boton" />  

    </center>

    <br>

    </form>

    </center>

  <script type="text/javascript">

      //variables para llegar a el canvas --->

      var canvas = document.getElementById("miCanvas");

      var contexto = canvas.getContext("2d");

      function colorfondo() {

        //Lo vuelve a crear el fondo gris --->

        contexto.fillStyle = "#3A3A3A";

        //crea el fondo del tamaño ancho y alto del canvas --->

        contexto.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      }

      colorfondo()


      function limpiar() {

        // limpia los campos de texto --->

        document.f1.reset();

        colorfondo();

      }

      function dibujar() {

        //variables para llegar a el canvas --->

        colorfondo();

        //variable para lo ancho --->

        var n1 = document.f1.txtn1.value;

        var v1 = parseInt(25) + parseInt(n1);

        //variable para lo alto --->

        var n2 = document.f1.txtn2.value;

        var v2 = parseInt(25) + parseInt(n2);

        contexto.beginPath();

        // 25 es de posición de margen

        contexto.moveTo(v1, 25); //aquí va la anchura 1

        contexto.lineTo(25, 25);

        contexto.lineTo(25, v2); // aquí va la altura 2

        //color del triángulo --->

        contexto.fillStyle ="#fff"

        contexto.fill();

      }

    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para empezar voy a crear un ejemplo muy sencillo en el cual dibujo un  rectángulo en el canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("miCanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var el_color = "#ff0000";
ctx.fillStyle = el_color;


function Dibujar(){
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 280, 180);
}


window.addEventListener("load", inicializar, false);

function inicializar() {
  input_color = document.querySelector("[type='color']");
  input_color.value = el_color;
  Dibujar();
  input_color.addEventListener("input", actualizar1, false);
  input_color.addEventListener("change", actualizar2, false);
  input_color.select(); //llama el método select() para seleccionar el valor de input_color si es un input type text
}
function actualizar1(event) {
  el_color = event.target.value;
}
  
 
function actualizar2(event) {
  ctx.fillStyle = el_color;
  Dibujar();
}
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="miCanvas" width="300" height="200">Su navegador no soporta Canvas.</canvas>

<label>Color:</label>
<input type="color">
```

A continuación viene tu código con unos cuantos cambios: en el HTML he añadido un input type color para que el usuario pueda escoger el color deseado. También en el javascript he añadido las funciones y los eventos del ejemplo anterior para poder cambiar el color del triangulo.

```js
//variables para llegar a el canvas --->

      var canvas = document.getElementById("miCanvas");

      var contexto = canvas.getContext("2d");
      
      var el_color = "#ff0000";
      var v1=0, v2=0;
      //ctx.fillStyle = el_color;

      function colorfondo() {

        //Lo vuelve a crear el fondo gris --->

        contexto.fillStyle = "#3A3A3A";

        //crea el fondo del tamaño ancho y alto del canvas --->

        contexto.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      }

      colorfondo()


      function limpiar() {

        // limpia los campos de texto --->

        document.f1.reset();

        colorfondo();

      }

      function dibujar() {

        //variables para llegar a el canvas --->

        colorfondo();

        //variable para lo ancho --->

        var n1 = document.f1.txtn1.value;

        v1 = parseInt(25) + parseInt(n1);

        //variable para lo alto --->

        var n2 = document.f1.txtn2.value;

        v2 = parseInt(25) + parseInt(n2);

        triangulo()

      }



function triangulo(){
  contexto.beginPath();

        // 25 es de posición de margen
  
  if(v1 > 0 && v2 > 0){

        contexto.moveTo(v1, 25); //aquí va la anchura 1

        contexto.lineTo(25, 25);

        contexto.lineTo(25, v2); // aquí va la altura 2

        //color del triángulo --->

        contexto.fillStyle = el_color;

        contexto.fill();}
}



window.addEventListener("load", primeraFuncion, false);

function primeraFuncion() {
  input_color = document.querySelector("[type='color']");
  input_color.value = el_color;
  //Dibujar();
  input_color.addEventListener("input", actualizar1, false);
  input_color.addEventListener("change", actualizar2, false);
  input_color.select();//llama el método select() para seleccionar el valor de input_color si es un input type text
}
function actualizar1(event) {
  el_color = event.target.value;
  }


function actualizar2(event) {
  triangulo()
}
```

```css
 body{

      background-color: #F1F1F1;

    }

    form {

      padding: 0;

      margin:10px 30px ;

      background-color: white;

    }

    *{

      margin: 0;

      padding: 0;

      font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";

    }

    input[type=button]{

      text-decoration:none;

      border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);

      font-size: 20px;

      color: #fff;

      cursor: pointer;

      display: inline-block;

      border-radius: 5px;

      height: 32px;

      width: 235px;

      background-color: #11B547;

    }

    /* boton al clickearlo sobre el */

    input[type=button]:active{

      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.00);

      color: #11B547;

    }

    /*este espara que el imput number se le quite las flechitas*/

    input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{-webkit-appearance: none;margin: 0;}/*google chrome y safari*/

    input[type=number]::-o-inner-spin-button{-o-appearance: none;margin: 0;}/*opera*/

    input[type=number]::-moz-inner-spin-button{-moz-appearance:none;margin: 0;}/* firefox*/

    input[type=number] {-moz-appearance:textfield; margin:5px;}/*firefox firefox 29*/

    input[type=number]::-ms-inner-spin-button{-ms-appearance: none;margin: 0;}/*internet explorer*/

    input[type=number] {

      cursor: text;

      text-indent: 5px;

      width: 355px;

      font-size: 20px;

      height: 30px;

      border-radius: 5px;

      margin: 0;

      background: linear-gradient(#342E21, #483F2E);

      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #483F2E inset;

      padding: 0px;

      border: none;

      color: #fff;

    }

    header{

      background-color: #fff;

      width: 100%;

      height: 50px;

 

    }

    header span{

      float: left;

      vertical-align:bottom;

      font-size:35px;

    }
```

```html
<center>

    

  <form name="f1">

    <h1>Triángulo personalizable</h1><br>

    <input type="number" name="txtn1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tamaño Horizontal">

    <input type="number" name="txtn2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tamaño Vertical">

    <br><br>

    <canvas id="miCanvas" width="720" height="450">Su navegador no soporta Canvas.</canvas>

    <br>

    <center>

    <input type="button" value="Dibujar" onclick="dibujar()">

    <input type="button" value="Limpiar" onclick="limpiar()">

    <input type="button" onclick=" location.href='index.html' " value="Volver al Inicio" name="boton" /> 
      
      
    <input type="color" />

    </center>

    <br>

    </form>

    </center>
```

Answer (score -1):

Aca te propongo una solución. Por defecto pinta en blanco como estaba antes. Pero si el usuario quiere, puede elegir un color, y volver a dibujar el triangulo con el color elegido.
Para esto use una función que toma el color pasado por parametro, y lo guarda en una variable. Esa variable es la q se usa despues a la hora de darle el color:

```
contexto.fillStyle = colorTriangulo;
```

```js
//variables para llegar a el canvas --->

var canvas = document.getElementById("miCanvas");

var contexto = canvas.getContext("2d");

var colorTriangulo = "#fff";

function colorfondo() {

  //Lo vuelve a crear el fondo gris --->

  contexto.fillStyle = "#3A3A3A";

  //crea el fondo del tamaño ancho y alto del canvas --->

  contexto.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

}

colorfondo();

function limpiar() {

  // limpia los campos de texto --->

  document.f1.reset();

  colorfondo();

}



function dibujar() {

  //variables para llegar a el canvas --->

  colorfondo();

  //variable para lo ancho --->

  var n1 = document.f1.txtn1.value;

  var v1 = parseInt(25) + parseInt(n1);

  //variable para lo alto --->

  var n2 = document.f1.txtn2.value;

  var v2 = parseInt(25) + parseInt(n2);

  contexto.beginPath();

  // 25 es de posición de margen

  contexto.moveTo(v1, 25); //aquí va la anchura 1

  contexto.lineTo(25, 25);

  contexto.lineTo(25, v2); // aquí va la altura 2

  //color del triángulo --->

  contexto.fillStyle = colorTriangulo;

  contexto.fill();

}

function setColor(color){
  colorTriangulo = color;
}
function showColorPanel(){
  document.getElementById('colores').style.display = 'flex';
}
```

```css
body{

      background-color: #F1F1F1;

    }

    form {

      padding: 0;

      margin:10px 30px ;

      background-color: white;

    }

    *{

      margin: 0;

      padding: 0;

      font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "sans-serif";

    }

    input[type=button]{

      text-decoration:none;

      border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.00);

      font-size: 20px;

      color: #fff;

      cursor: pointer;

      display: inline-block;

      border-radius: 5px;

      height: 32px;

      width: 235px;

      background-color: #11B547;

    }

    /* boton al clickearlo sobre el */

    input[type=button]:active{

      background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.00);

      color: #11B547;

    }

    /*este espara que el imput number se le quite las flechitas*/

    input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button{-webkit-appearance: none;margin: 0;}/*google chrome y safari*/

    input[type=number]::-o-inner-spin-button{-o-appearance: none;margin: 0;}/*opera*/

    input[type=number]::-moz-inner-spin-button{-moz-appearance:none;margin: 0;}/* firefox*/

    input[type=number] {-moz-appearance:textfield; margin:5px;}/*firefox firefox 29*/

    input[type=number]::-ms-inner-spin-button{-ms-appearance: none;margin: 0;}/*internet explorer*/

    input[type=number] {

      cursor: text;

      text-indent: 5px;

      width: 355px;

      font-size: 20px;

      height: 30px;

      border-radius: 5px;

      margin: 0;

      background: linear-gradient(#342E21, #483F2E);

      box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #483F2E inset;

      padding: 0px;

      border: none;

      color: #fff;

    }

    header{

      background-color: #fff;

      width: 100%;

      height: 50px;

 

    }

    header span{

      float: left;

      vertical-align:bottom;

      font-size:35px;

    }
    
 #colores{
  display: none;
  margin: 10px auto auto auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color : #3A3A3A;
}
.color{
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: solid 1px white;
  /* float: left; */
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 2px 5px auto 5px;
}
#colores #negro{background-color: black;}
#colores #blanco{background-color: white;}
#colores #rosa{background-color: #fbb6d3;}
#colores #azul{background-color: #6eb7d7;}
#colores #rojo{background-color: #f26866;}
#colores #verde{background-color: #86ca5d;}
#colores #amarillo{background-color: #ffed51;}
#colores #marron{background-color: #c0ba98;}
#colores #naranja{background-color: #fcaa85;}
#colores #violeta{background-color: #a58ac1;}
```

```html
<!Doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Triángulo</title>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <center>
    <form name="f1">
      <h1>Triángulo personalizable</h1><br>
      <input type="number" name="txtn1" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tamaño Horizontal">
      <input type="number" name="txtn2" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Tamaño Vertical">
      <br><br>
      <canvas id="miCanvas" width="720" height="450">Su navegador no soporta Canvas.</canvas>
      <br>
      <center>
        <input type="button" value="Dibujar" onclick="dibujar()">
        <input type="button" value="Limpiar" onclick="limpiar()">
        <input type="button" value="Elegir Color" onclick="showColorPanel();" />
        <input type="button" onclick=" location.href='index.html' " value="Volver al Inicio" name="boton" />

        <div id="colores">
          <div style="display:inline-flex;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
            <div class="color" onclick="setColor('#000000');" id="negro"></div>
            <div class="color" onclick="setColor('#ffffff');" id="blanco"></div>
            <div class="color" onclick="setColor('#fbb6d3');" id="rosa"></div>
            <div class="color" onclick="setColor('#6eb7d7');" id="azul"></div>
            <div class="color" onclick="setColor('#f26866');" id="rojo"></div>
            <div class="color" onclick="setColor('#86ca5d');" id="verde"></div>
            <div class="color" onclick="setColor('#ffed51');" id="amarillo"></div>
            <div class="color" onclick="setColor('#c0ba98');" id="marron"></div>
            <div class="color" onclick="setColor('#fcaa85');" id="naranja"></div>
            <div class="color" onclick="setColor('#a58ac1');" id="violeta"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </center>
      <br>
    </form>
  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @ManucoBianco.Me parece guay como queda perfecto Manuco ! Sabrias como poner una vez esta pintado del palo las dimensiones de la figura dibujadas rollo si pone 100 y 100 arriba pues salgan las dimensiones de 100x100

Comment: Tambien girar el triangulo y tener la base en el suelo y centrar la imagen en el centro que queda arriba y no ha de estar así gracias!

Comment: Veo que puedo hacer con lo del borde y lo de poner los px, mas trade edito. Lo de girar y mover el triangulo te lo dejo a ti, eso ya no es parte de la pregunta.